# Use of templates with templated Deck class

Tags: c++, template, playing-cards

I have previous revisions of my deck of cards project, but I may not need to link them here since the emphasis is on the use of templates.

I've never used them before until now, and I like how intuitive my implementation has become.  However, I'm also aware that there are many pitfalls in C++ templates.  Although I don't think this implementation uses them heavily, I'd still like to know if I'm at a good start before I use them again.

I'm also a bit unsure about some of my naming now, considering this is a template class.  For instance, I've changed `add()`'s parameter from `card` to `item` because it cannot be assumed that the user will only use cards.  Although it makes sense to just use cards (or anything representing cards), it would not seem practical to limit the implementation to just that usage.  I would prefer this to be reusable.

Of course, I'm okay with any other improvements that can be made.

**Deck.hpp**

```
#ifndef DECK_HPP
#define DECK_HPP

#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template <class T> class Deck
{
private:
    std::vector<T> original;
    std::vector<T> playable;

public:
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type SizeType;

    void add(T const&);
    T draw();
    void reset();
    void shuffle();
    SizeType size() const { return playable.size(); }
    bool empty() const { return playable.empty(); }
};

template <class T> void Deck<T>::add(T const& item)
{
    original.push_back(item);
    playable.push_back(item);
}

template <class T> T Deck<T>::draw()
{
    if (playable.empty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("deck empty");
    }

    T top(playable.back());
    playable.pop_back();
    return top;
}

template <class T> void Deck<T>::reset()
{
    playable = original;
}

template <class T> void Deck<T>::shuffle()
{
    if (!playable.empty())
    {
        std::random_shuffle(playable.begin(), playable.end());
    }
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bottom line: your code here is focused and solid. It's a well-written introductory use of templates. However I'm not sure it's a great scenario in which to use them. First I'll talk about ways to improve its reusability, and then I'll say more about why I think it's a questionable scenario.

As you start trying to implement your own templatized data structure, there are a lot of concerns to think about. Above all else you need to consider how your data structure will be used; what operations will consumers of it expect, what limitations will they have to put up with, and whether any of the data structure's implementation choices lock them into bad patterns. In general I would say you would do well to follow the lead of the STL data structures unless you have specific reasons not to. Here are a few of the places where you currently differ:

#### `void Deck<T>::add(T const &)`

This one actually is pretty much spot on. But I want to talk about the implications of how it's implemented. You are requiring `T` to be copyable. Thus if a consumer of this class needs to compare cards, `T` will need to compare itself through means other than by its address. This isn't particularly unusual, but I just wanted to be clear that comparing `T` instances by address is invalidated by `Deck<T>`'s implementation.

The biggest question mark here is the lack of a range insertion, perhaps via constructor or `add(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)`. Similarly there's no index-based insertion, but that wouldn't mix well with the two vectors that are often out of sync.

#### `T Deck<T>::draw()`

Before C++11 introduced move semantics, there was not necessarily a low cost way to examine and remove an item from a data structure. This is why vector and other data structures let you examine the front or back, but don't return the removed item on a pop_back(). While it's perfectly good to wrap the functionality of the underlying storage, as the cost of copying T goes up, so does the cost of this implementation of `draw()`. Implementing it in some other fashion (typically as two separate methods for peeking and removing) is suggested before C++11.

> Taking into account what Corbin and Loki Astari point out, it's more relevant to consider weak and strong exception guarantees (essentially the ability to reason about correctness in unusual situations) instead of the cost of copying (thanks especially to RVO). Whether you need to care about either is still completely dependent on your use case in practice, and thus only of extreme importance in general purpose data structures, or in ones you know need to offer it.

#### Inside `draw()`

Your implementation of `draw()` verifies that the playable deck has items remaining. This is certainly good for catching errors, but leads to repeated checks for the same data. Either the calling code will look like `while (true) { ::: draw(); ::: }` and will have to use a `try/catch` to find out when the deck was empty, or it will look like `while (!deck.empty()) { ::: draw(); ::: }`. The former is a questionable way to use exceptions, as an empty deck is hardly an unexpected condition, but the latter means both the caller and callee are repeating the empty check. It's also possible that the caller knows this in other ways, such as having put 52 cards in the deck and then looping 52 times to empty it.

As an aside, it can still be useful to have this sort of check available by another name (consider the difference between `vector<T>::operator[]` and `vector<T>::at`), or available through a compile-time option (such as a `DEBUG` build). But it's typically good to make an unchecked version available (vector's operator[] case).

#### `void Deck<T>::reset()`

I'm lumping a couple comments in here, and this is less about following the STL's lead. Like in `draw()`, as the cost of copying `T` goes up or the size of your deck goes up, so does the cost of `reset()`; is it possible that you don't need to save the original order? If you don't, then perhaps it would be better to consider a different implementation:
one `vector<T>` containing the order of the deck, one `vector<T>::const_iterator` or `vector<T>::size_type` containing the index/iterator through which you've already played. This would have a lot of repercussions, so I'm going to show the methods that it would impact, assuming the class has a `size_type deck_top`, and that we remove `original`. I like the shorter code, but that has less to do with the index and more to do with the other changes.

```
template <class T> bool Deck<T>::empty() const
{
    return deck_top >= playable.size();
}

template <class T> T const & Deck<T>::draw() // note we can now return a reference
{
    return playable[deck_top++];
}

template <class T> void Deck<T>::reset()
{
    deck_top = 0;
}

template <class T> void Deck<T>::shuffle()
{
    std::random_shuffle(playable.begin() + deck_top, playable.end());
}
```

This of course has multiple tradeoffs besides the ones I already mentioned. Perhaps the biggest is that there's still no way to remove cards (temporarily or permanently), so it's hard to model a game that shuffles a partial deck while people are still holding some cards in their hands. I think you will rapidly find that it's hard to make this data structure usable for all the scenarios you think you want it to support without making it almost as generic as vector itself. At which point you will have to consider whether it's worth reusing the data structure, or if it's really just for a single program's use.

#### Final notes

As a generic comment, I'm undecided on `card` vs. `item`. I think `card` conveys the intended use better, and doesn't really get in the way if someone wants, say, a "Deck" of tiles instead. But I do agree in general with the point about not boxing yourself in by your parameter names.

Comment: Fun fact to add to your `T Deck<T>::draw()` section: `T pop_back()` is impossible to implement correctly unless `T`'s copy constructor is not allowed to throw exceptions. This undoubtedly affected the decision to have `pop_back` return void too. Even if performance were not a concern, `pop_back` would return void. (Oh, and move operations can throw exceptions, so `T pop_back` is still impossible.)

Comment: I especially like your point about the modelling of card removal.  This was one of my biggest obstacles, and it appears that I may not be able to do this correct.  @Corbin told me in an earlier review that this implementation would be no different than maintaining an STL data structure and putting cards into that.  I do agree with him on that.  That also leads me to agree with your point regarding reusability.

Comment: When I mentioned this, I was referring to my own programs.  I know that someone else can just use an STL container and put it into a sorting function or something, but I personally wanted to use something generic and... well, personalized for my own use.  I still want it to be *good*, of course.  But from what I see, I'm best off making it as proper as an STL container as possible, while not needing to account for everything (such as all the operator overloads and iterators).  And yes, I do still want to make sure I'm not misusing templates early on.

Comment: I also don't have full access to C++11 on my machine, so I don't think I could properly test move semantics, even if I wanted to here.  So, to ease the confusion, I'll just consider this a C++03 program.

Comment: @Jamal To lightly contradict myself, especially in the case you describe of personal use only, it's not at all required to match STL. (Like you say, save iterators for later.) [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) is an important mindset to remember. Just balance it with avoiding gratuitous differences with other classes you'll use.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: Thanks for the reminder about YAGNI. :-) I will do just that, and leave out some unneeded functionality such as some operator overloads and iterators (I haven't written the latter for any program before anyway).

Comment: Don't agree with your arguments about copying in `T Deck<T>::draw()` I think this argument is very outdated . All modern compilers have exceedingly good RVO and NRVO build in. The copy will be elided.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I didn't like returning by reference anyway, and I don't think my own `Card` class is too large to copy inexpensively (if it's even relevant here).

Comment: @Jamal: Return by value is usually not expensive (put prints in to check). The RVO and NRVO optimizations will kick in and the copy will be elided.

Comment: My approach to removing a card from my Deck class: track n_remaining (originally 52 if a standard deck). Pick a number from 0-51. Decrement n_remaining. Swap that card with the (n_remaining)th. Reshuffle is just reset n_remaining to 52.

Answer (score 6):

The usage of a template parameter named `T` is generally idiomatic when there are no restrictions on what you can use when instantiating the template; for example, when using container classes `T` is used as it could potentially be anything. If the parameter is more limited however, you should give it a more descriptive name. In this example, an obvious choice would be `Card`:

```
template <typename Card>
class Deck
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good point.  I suppose there will be confusion if the user uses, say, `int`s, but that it inevitable with templates.

Comment: I disagree. The templatized parameter are generic they can be anything thus trying to name this counterproductive. I generally use `T` for a normal type or `I` for an iterator.

Answer (score 4):

The only additional point I have is the use of class:

```
template <class T> class Deck 
    //    ^^^^^^
          This one.
```

Its technically valid. But the implications that T should be some class type (or user defined type) make me dislike this form. I prefer the modern version:

```
template <typename T>  // PS. I also prefer line break here.
class Deck             //     It makes the class look like a normal class
```

Answer (score 3):

- I did have access to C++11 when writing this code, but I never found a use for it at the time.  I am now aware that there's a better replacement for `std::random_shuffle()` available in C++11 which doesn't utilize `rand` ([now considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)): [`std::shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

  This requires a third parameter, a random number engine, supplied as such:

  ```
  static std::random_device rd;
  static std::mt19937 engine(rd());
  ```

  (The new C++11 library [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) is required for this.)

  In `shuffle()`, I can now replace `std::random_shuffle()` with `std::shuffle()`:

  ```
  std::shuffle(playable.begin(), playable.end(), engine);
  ```

  With this, I can also now remove `std::srand()` from the driver.
- Since neither `size()` nor `empty()` throw exceptions, I can add `noexcept` for both of them to make this clear:

  ```
  SizeType size() const noexcept { return playable.size(); }
  bool empty() const noexcept { return playable.empty(); }
  ```
- I can now use type aliasing for the type `std::vector<T>`:

  ```
  using Cards = std::vector<T>;
  ```

  This would allow me to change the type in just one place:

  ```
  Cards original;
  Cards playable;
  ```
- Due to templating issues and a possible lack of `size_type` for a different container class, I can remove `SizeType` and have `size()` return `auto` (in C++14):

  ```
  auto size() const noexcept { return playable.size(); }
  ```